# How to get maven version in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am creating CI pipeline with Jenkins. Need to tag the docker images with the Maven version of the project, e.g. `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

Although, maven version is exposed as `POM_VERSION` based on [this Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20594), it seems to apply only to the "Maven project". I tried to use the variable in Pipeline's Jenkins file as `${POM_VERSION}` and it did not recognize the property.

What is the best way to get the version number? Parse the pom.xml and grep the version with a bash script and call it inside `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: What maven plugin are you using for creating docker images?

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF spotify

Comment: You can name your image this way `<imageName>${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</imageName>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tag docker image with project version using Spotify docker maven plugin as follows :

```
<imageTags>
    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
    <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
</imageTags>

<imageName>${image.suffix}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</imageName>
```

Comment: How to control when to use which tag?

Comment: You mean how to control which tag to use when running docker image?

Comment: What is the `imageTags` blocks for? Why do we need multiple tags?

Comment: Please refer to docker tags documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/